# How to set-up Hybris 6.7 local with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sap-commerce-cloud, commerce

I am trying to set-up a local Hybris Instant with MySQL instead of HSQLDB.

**local.properties**

```
 mysql.optional.tabledefs=CHARSET\=utf8 COLLATE\=utf8_bin
 db.url=jdbc\:mysql\://localhost/6showcase?useConfigs\=maxPerformance&characterEncoding\=utf8&useSSL\=false
 db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 db.username=root
 db.password=root
 db.tableprefix=
 mysql.tabletype=InnoDB
 installed.tenants=**
```

Build Successfully(ant clean all).

Getting runti:

```
**ERROR [localhost-startStop-4] [DataSourceImpl] error connecting to DataSource having url jdbc:mysql://localhost/6showcase?useConfigs=maxPerformance&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long**
```

Using user root with all privileges for the schema etc...
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3h0gL.jpg)
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQbkh.jpg)

Any idea what can be wrong?

Comment: Don't you miss the mysql port (default 3306)? If it don't solve the pb then check the db name. It's valid to start a db name with a digit but it might be an issue in hybris I've never tried.

Answer (score 0):

You need exact db version, last or old version not supported. hybris 6.7 need MySQL 5.6 or 5.7 (with connector 5.1.x)

Full supported database list: https://help.hybris.com/6.7.0/hcd/8c71300f866910149b40c88dfc0de431.html

Comment: Good note, I installed the latest MySQL 8.0 so there might be an issue. Will try with 5.6 or 5.7 as recommended! Thank's

Answer (score 0):

Follow
https://help.hybris.com/6.7.0/hcd/8c15bfb58669101484b7de3f3145855e.html

**Please Note:**
The MySQL connector is not shipped with SAP Hybris Commerce. Please [download](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) the file and put it in the `${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}/platform/lib/dbdriver` folder.

Comment: The connector was included during my build as you indicated. But good comment.

Comment: Check for the version as @mkysoft suggested